# MongoDB ReduceMap An Array Property that Contains Another Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm still new to MongoDB and non-relational databases in general so if the answer to my question is "Dude, you're thinking about your data in the wrong way", please let me know.

That being said, here's what I'm after. I have the following data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("549b26b370b452eeb6acecd3"),
    "user" : "54530e03c575dc86d61d22f8",
    "workHistory" : [ 
        {
            "description" : "",
            "endDate" : null,
            "name" : "My Company",
            "skills" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acecd4")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acecd5")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acecda")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acecdb")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acecdd")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acece9")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acecea")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b995b70b452eeb6acecf9")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b999470b452eeb6acecfa")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b9ab670b452eeb6acecfb")
                }
            ],
            "startDate" : "2013-10-01"
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "",
            "endDate" : "2013-10-01",
            "name" : "Another Company",
            "skills" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acecd4")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acecd5")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acecdb")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acecdd")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acece1")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acece9")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("549b995b70b452eeb6acecf9")
                }
            ],
            "startDate" : "2012-04-01"
        }, 
        .....
```

What I am trying to do is resolve that data I can list the actual skill names under "skills" instead of just object ID's. For reference here's the skills collection:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acecd4"),
    "name" : "CSS",
    "description" : ""
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acecd5"),
    "name" : "HTML5",
    "description" : ""
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acecd6"),
    "name" : "Ruby",
    "description" : ""
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("549b29c970b452eeb6acecd7"),
    "name" : "Ruby on Rails",
    "description" : ""
}
```

I've tried looking into using MapReduce to do some kind of join, but I can barely wrap my head around it and all the [examples](http://blog.knoldus.com/2014/03/12/easiest-way-to-implement-joins-in-mongodb-2-4/) I'm finding don't have data this complex.

What's the best approach for getting my desired result? Side note: I'm not 100% sure that simply embedding the skills in the "skills" property is the right approach. I'm trying to keep them separate because the skills may be listed in other areas of my application separate from work history.

Comment: Your data sample does not contain any of those "skill names" therefore I assume what you actually mean is getting the data matching those `_id` values under "skills" which refers to either other items in the collection or in fact in another collection. Especially in the latter case this is "joining" and MongoDB does not do joins with other collections in a single query. You either live with that or consider re-designing your schema to "embed" the data without using another collection. Which is kind of the point of a No-SQL solution. To do things differently.

Comment: As @NeilLunn mentioned, mongodb itself does not support joins. But if you would like to keep data this way, you would need a client that has an implementation to resolve references for you, or you would yourself have to make multiple queries to resolve the references. One such client is the Mongoose API (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). Map Reduce, though can be used to resolve references, have to be run each time data in the collection changes and is not the best option here.

Comment: @BatScream really not sure what your point here was to add value. I also think you "mistyped" here as mapReduce **cannot** resolve references from another collection. I Usually post comments when there is not an obvious duplicate question and an "answer" is not productive in the context. Advocacy of higher level API offerings is usually not productive. But if you feel the need then do so.

Comment: @NeilLunn, I was referring to the link that the OP posted, Map-reduce is being used to dump the joined results into a new collection. I was wrong in referring it to as "resolve references". Sure will definitely consider advocating higher level APIs only when required.